# Got errors trying to compile buck

Tags: python, ant, buck

I followed the instructions at https://buckbuild.com/setup/getting_started.html in the Build From Source section to try and build Buck from the git checkout and got the following errors. The prerequisites were installed correctly.

```
chrisym-mbp:buck chrisym$ ./bin/buck build --show-output buck
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 184, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 157, in main
    for dst, src in manifest["modules"].iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 184, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 157, in main
    for dst, src in manifest["modules"].iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 184, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 157, in main
    for dst, src in manifest["modules"].iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 184, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 157, in main
    for dst, src in manifest["modules"].iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 184, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 157, in main
    for dst, src in manifest["modules"].iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 184, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 157, in main
    for dst, src in manifest["modules"].iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Building: finished in 1.4 sec (100%) 76/1536 jobs, 19 updated
  Total time: 1.6 sec
Command failed with exit code 1.
stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 184, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/chrisym/Library/MobileTools/buck/ant-out/buck-modules-resources/python/make_pex.py", line 157, in main
    for dst, src in manifest["modules"].iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

    When running <pex>.
    When building rule //py/hash:hash_files.
chrisym-mbp:buck chrisym$
```

I tried it with Python 2 and Python 3. Same behavior in both cases.

Comment: Looks like something is trying to run Python 2 code with the Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: What happens if you switch to just `items()` instead?